# Use ASP.NET Membership e Profile in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-membership

I use classic ASP.NET Membership Provider in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. When I validate user by Membership.Validate() method, I set the value in FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() for persistent login during the navigation of the web site, but when i try to call the HttpContext.User.Identify.Name i get a String Empty value. Where is the problem?

P.S. In the past, i used the ASP.NET Web Forms Access Controls to do this job that automatize this mecanism.

Comment: What does Membership.Validate return?  When are you calling HttpContext.User.Identify.Name?  Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: What IIS authentication settings do you have?

Comment: Maybe something misconfigured in `web.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing a page refresh? (ie a RedirectToAction?)

The authentication cookie will not be valid until after a full page refresh has occurred.  If you check the HttpContext.User.Identity.Name right after you validate the user and set the cookie, this value will be null.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that i don't executed a RedirectToAction.